# Debugging Missing Elements in Taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, debug

I'm trying to debug an issue and I was hoping I could get some direction. With the same exact taxonomy page template, one of the pages is missing the sidebar and the WP admin bar (logged in), while the others all work as expected. Take a look at the following pages:

Not Working: http://banneroftruth.org/us/store/product-tag/eBooks/

Working: http://banneroftruth.org/us/store/product-tag/new-releases/
http://banneroftruth.org/us/store/product-tag/banner-classics/

Any idea what could cause this, and where should I start looking for answers?

Thanks for any help. :)

**UPDATE:** Footer is also missing, and this was working fine until yesterday

Comment: Look for any instance of a `body_class` that might be added to this specific page. Also, see how your navigation menus are registered

Comment: @PieterGoosen - thanks for your comment. Interestingly the classes are exactly the same, but I also realized the footer is missing too.

Comment: It looks like, if the current page term exists on the left menu item, the sidebar is visible. If the term not, the sidebar isn't. You should look for - `<nav id="localnav">` and check in which condition the element is being displayed.

Comment: @Shazzad thanks for the comment, but I don't think that's the issue for two reasons: 1. The ebook term does exist on the left menu item and 2. The nav shows up everywhere on the site regardless of page.